# Model driven form validation issue in Angular 2.0

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-validation

In Angular 2.0,  model driven form using Form Builder, I have,

```ts
 ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.fb.group({
        id: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
        name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]]
    });
    
    this.user.get('id').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
                alert("Change detected); 
                });
}
```

and in HTML I have :

```html
<input   type="text" formControlName="id" >
```

But what happening is for every letter I change in text box the  `alert("Change detected");`  is getting fired, instead after tabout only I need to call   `alert("Change detected")`.  I know in Angular 1.x to achieve this by using `ng-model-options` but how to achieve the same in Angular 2.0?

Comment: where you write this subscription?

Comment: in  ngOnInit(). Edited the question

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to onblur handler

```html
<input type="text" formControlName="id" (blur)="onBlur()">
```

and in class

```ts
onBlur(){
  alert("Change detected");  
}
```

Comment: shall I need to import anything for this blur event to fire?  Because after making this change the onBlur function is not at all triggering.

Comment: it's triggered at me